# The file {location} is treated as local but is inside a node_modules directory | Error HH1006

Tags: hardhat, compilation

I am trying to compile my contracts which are present in `./contracts` directory (normal hardhat setup), I am not using deploy script to compile, just trying to compile with `yarn hardhat compile`, it is showing following error -

```
The file "{location}" is treated as local but is inside a node_modules directory
```

There are import statements in my contracts which are not showing error and the matter of the fact is that this file at `{location}` is not even being imported in any of the contracts and because of it error is occurring, it is present in `node_modules`.

**I had placed a copy of the `node_modules` folder in contracts directory, so that I do not have to make changes for import statements in my contracts.**

Answer (score 1):

According to the hardhat docs, for the error `#HH1006: File from node_modules treated as local` if you aren't overriding compilation-related tasks, please report this error as a bug.

See: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/errors